# Can't generate FCM Token for some Devices

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've Two android devices 5.1.1 , 5.0.2 and emulator(Pixel2 api 28 (android 9) ) , for the first device (**5.1.1**) i can generate fcm token with no problem

I am using this code to generate token

```
irebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w("FCM_TOKEN", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                    return;
                }

                // Get new Instance ID token
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();

            }
        });
```

I am getting this exception when using the second device (5.0.2) and the emulator (android 9)

**05-26 01:10:01.115 13377-13402/com.abc.payapp E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED**

What kind of authentication required when generating tokens !

Comment: FCM don't work in simulator so in Simulator you cannot generate FCM token.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem on a ONEPLUS A6013 Android 9.0. I get the error on FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstance(). And also FirebaseIntentService.onNewToken(String s) never gets called.

Comment: Have u solve this issue? I am facing this issue. I want to know the solving steps.

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry FCM works fine in emulators.

Answer (score 1):

Using an emulator or device **WITHOUT** Google Play will cause this error.

Check the Google Play Store app on your device/emulator, make the update, and you should be good to go !

Comment: Good input thanks for that, but Mohamed Nor's question is about real devices.

Comment: that's what i said emulator or device ! :)